# If $\alpha'=f(\alpha)$ for some periodic $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R_{>0}$, then $\alpha(x+\ell)=\alpha(x)+A$ for some fixed $\ell$.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R_{>0}$ be some periodic Lipschitz function, $A>0$ some constant, and suppose that $f$ is $A$-periodic. Then the theory of ODEs tells us that we have global solutions $\alpha:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ to $$\alpha'(s)=f(\alpha(s))$$ for all initial values. Now, I suspect that if we set $$\ell=\int_x^{x+A}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{f(u)}$$ for any $x\in\Bbb R$, then $\alpha(x+\ell)=\alpha(x)+A$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$ (this problem comes from the theory of curves, in which we try to find a unit-length parametrization for a closed immersed plane curve).

But why is this true?

Comment: Suppose $\alpha(0)=\alpha_0$, and let $S:a\mapsto \int_{\alpha_0}^a f(u)^{-1}du$.  If $m=\inf_a f(a)$, then $\alpha'(s)\ge m>0$, so $\alpha$ is a homeomorphism on $\mathbb R$.  Since $S(\alpha_0)=0$ and $S'(\alpha(s))=\alpha'(s)^{-1}$, we have $S=\alpha^{-1}$.  Observe that $S(a+A)=S(a)+\int_{a}^{a+A}f(u)^{-1}du=S(a)+\ell$, such that $\alpha(S(a)+\ell)=a+A$.  Putting $S(a)=s$ and $a=\alpha(s)$ gives the result.

Comment: @user254433 That's easily sufficient to post as an answer, and I encourage you to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved this here from a comment:

Suppose $\alpha(0)=\alpha_0$, and let $$S= \int_{\alpha_0}^a \frac{\mathrm du}{f(u)}.$$  If $m=\inf_{a\in\mathbb R}f(a)$, then $\alpha'(s)\ge m>0$, so $\alpha$ is a homeomorphism on $\mathbb R$.  Since $S(\alpha_0)=0$ and $S'(\alpha(s))=\alpha'(s)^{-1}$, we have $S=\alpha^{-1}$.  Observe that $$S(a+A)=S(a)+\int_a^{a+A}\frac{\mathrm du}{f(u)}=S(a)+\ell$$ such that $\alpha(S(a)+\ell)=a+A$.  Putting $S(a)=s$ and $a=\alpha(s)$ gives the result.